# Bake action with euler rotation instead of quaternion

Tags: keyframes, rigid-body-simulation, rigify, actions, quaternion

there is a problem that baking actions with Euler rotation creates a flickering rotation in the keyframes. The problem can be solved by choosing quaternion as rotation but I need to export the keyframes which require an Euler rotation. How can I fix this flickering issue? Is there a way to bake actions properly with euler rotation? I tried to convert the quaternion rotation to euler rotation but it didn't work, the flickering returned.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround or temporal fix. In Blender version 2.92 (at this moment alpha version) the euler discontinuity filter has been improved. If you select the problematic bone, which has a flickering rotation after baking the action with euler rotation, you go into the Graph Editor -> Key -> Discontinuity Filter (Euler) at the top. At the moment, it fixes many of the rotation flickering but not all of them. Maybe in the future, it will fix all of the problematic keyframes, as it is still alpha.
Maybe this also helps other people with the same issue.